# Node GD on an M1 Mac mini

Tags: c++, node.js, macos, gd, apple-m1

Having a nightmare trying to install node GD (node sharp) on an M1 Mac mini.

I install node sharp from  source `npm install sharp --build-from-source`, and it fails on GD.... says it cannot find the GD C header file.

```
❯ npm install sharp                                                                                                                                                                                                          at 12:26:24

> node-gd@1.6.1 install /Users/rob/project9/node_modules/node-gd
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_gd/cpp/addon.o
In file included from ../cpp/addon.cc:2:
../cpp/node_gd.h:21:10: fatal error: 'gd.h' file not found
#include <gd.h>
         ^~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_gd/cpp/addon.o] Error 1
```

I'm assuming this is a pathing issue? - but I don't know enough to fix it?